# Get data attributes in table all tr

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, tr

I have table like this:

```
  <tr class="alignC even" data-pdp-id="10" role="row"> 
  <tr class="alignC even" data-pdp-id="11" role="row">
  <tr class="alignC even" data-pdp-id="12" role="row"> 
  <tr class="alignC even" data-pdp-id="13" role="row"> 
  <tr class="alignC even" data-pdp-id="14" role="row">
```

How can I get an array contains all data-pdp-id with jquery

Comment: highly encourage you to try something by yourself first...! Otherwise there are N number of ways to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use each to loop through tr element, inside each iteration, you can get the pdp-id, then push it in pre-defined array.

```
var pdpArr = [];
$('.alignC').each(function() {
    pdpArr.push($(this).data('pdp-id'));
});
console.log(pdpArr); // You can get the array of pdp-id at this point
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Awesome - much better. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can use either `.attr("data-pdp-id")` or `.data("pdp-id")`

Then when you have the data push it to an arr. `arr.push($(this).data("pdp-id"))`

```js
var arr = []
$("table tr.alignC").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr("data-pdp-id"))
})


$("table tr").each(function() {
  arr.push($(this).attr("data-pdp-id"))
})

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="alignC even" data-pdp-id="10" role="row">
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="alignC even" data-pdp-id="11" role="row">
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="alignC even" data-pdp-id="12" role="row">
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="alignC even" data-pdp-id="13" role="row">
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="alignC even" data-pdp-id="14" role="row">
    <td>14</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop and get that value using data and push that value in array.

```
var ID=[];
$('#TableID').find('tr').each(function() {
  ID.push($(this).data('pdp-id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ids=[];
    $('#tableId tr').each(function(){
      ids.push($(this).attr('data-pdp-id'))
    })
```

check this one